# django: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, tuples, typeerror

Getting a type error, 'tuple' object is not callable. Any idea what it could be? (dont worry about the indentation. It copies in weird.) I'm trying to create choices based on PackSize of storeliquor.

Views.py:

```
def storeliquor(request, store_id, liquor_id):        
a = StoreLiquor.objects.get(StoreLiquorID=liquor_id)
s = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
x = Order.objects.get(storeID=s, Active=True)
y = a.OffPremisePrice
c = a.BottleSize

g = request.POST.get('OrderAmount', '')
b = a.PackSize
h = b*2
d = b*3
e = b*4
r = b*5
if c == "1750 ML":
    pack_size = (
        ('1', '1')
        ('3', '3')
        (b, b)
        (h, h)
        (d, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    )
elif c == "1000 ML":
    pack_size = (
        ('1', '1')
        ('3', '3')
        ('6', '6')
        (b, b)
        (h, h)
        (d, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    )
elif c == "750 ML":
    pack_size = (
        ('1', '1')
        ('3', '3')
        ('6', '6')
        (b, b)
        (h, h)
        (c, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    )     
elif c == "375 ML":
    pack_size = (
        ('3', '3')
        ('6', '6')
        ('12', '12')
        (b, b)
        (h, h)
        (d, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    )        
elif c == "200 ML":
    pack_size = (
        ('12', '24')
        ('24', '24')
        (b, b)
        (c, c)
        (c, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    ) 
else:
    pack_size = (
        (b, b)
        (c, c)
        (c, d)
        (e, e)
        (r, r)
    )        




if request.method == "POST":
    f = AddToOrderForm(request.POST)

    if f.is_valid():
        z = f.save(commit=False)
        z.TotalPrice = (float(y)) * (float(g))
        z.storeliquorID = a
        z.orderID = x

        z.save()        

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/stores/get/%s' % store_id)

else:
    f = AddToOrderForm()
    f.fields['OrderAmount'].choices = pack_size      
args = {}


args['liquor'] = a
args['s'] = s
args['form'] = f   

return render(request,'storeliquor.html', args)
```

Models file:

```
class LiquorOrder(models.Model):

LiquorOrderID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
storeliquorID = models.ForeignKey(StoreLiquor)
orderID = models.ForeignKey(Order)
OrderAmount = models.CharField('Order Amount', max_length=3)
TotalPrice = models.DecimalField('Total Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
StorePrice = models.DecimalField('Store Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Forms file:

```
class AddToOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = LiquorOrder
    fields = ('OrderAmount', 'StorePrice')
```

Comment: The tuples inside `pack_size` should be separated by commas.(`,`)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You're missing comma (`,`) inbetween:

```
>>> ((1,2) (2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Put comma:

```
>>> ((1,2), (2,3))
((1, 2), (2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is comma missing in your tuple.

insert the comma between the tuples
as shown:

`pack_size = (('1', '1'),('3', '3'),(b, b),(h, h),(d, d),   (e, e),(r, r))`

Do the same for all

Answer (score 1):

**Tuple** needs **commas** between values as shown below:

```py
myTuple = (("a", "b"), (1, 2))
               ↑     ↑   ↑
           # Commas are needed
```

In addition, this below is **Tuple type**:

```py
myTuple = (("a", "b"))
```

And these below are also **Tuple type**:

```py
myTuple = (("a",))
```

```py
myTuple = (("a"),)
```

```py
myTuple = (("a",),)
```

```py
myTuple = ((),)
```

```py
myTuple = (())
```

But, this below is not **Tuple**. This below is **String type**:

```py
myTuple = (("a"))
```

And this below causes error:

```py
myTuple = ((,))
```