# 'tuple' object is not callable , machine learning API using Django API

Tags: python, django

I am trying build a machine learning API using DJANGO rest framework API. After creating a project and configuring model.py of created project 'MyAPI' ,for required approvals. And used the following commend to run the server, got following error.
how to fix them ?, Please guide me.

````C:\Users\Padmini\DjangoAPI>python manage.py runserver```
**error**

`````
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\DjangoAPI\MyAPI\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class approvals(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\DjangoAPI\MyAPI\models.py", line 7, in approvals
    ('Female','Female')
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable````
`````

**my model.py as following code**

``````
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class approvals(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES= (
    ('Male', 'Male')
    ('Female','Female')
    )
    MARRIED_CHOICES=(
    ('Yes','Yes'),
    ('No','No')
    )
    GRADUATED_CHOICES= (
    ('Graduate','Graduated'),
    ('Not_Graduate','Not_Graduate')
    )
    SELFEMPLOYED_CHOICES=(
    ('Yes','Yes'),
    ('No','No')
    )
    PROPERTY_CHOICES=(
    ('Rural','Rural'),
    ('Semiurban','Semiurban'),
    ('Urban','Urban')
    )
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dependants=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    applicantincome=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    coapplicatincome=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    loanamt=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    loanterm=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    credithistory=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    married=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=MARRIED_CHOICES)
    graduatededucation=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GRADUATED_CHOICES)
    selfemployed=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SELFEMPLOYED_CHOICES)
    area=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PROPERTY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.lastname, self.firstname)`````
``````

Comment: It looks like you're missing some comma's in between your tuples. Look at this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414708/django-typeerror-tuple-object-is-not-callable.

Comment: End any line which contains a tuple with a comma, even if it's the last one.